# jQuery depended select boxes (chosen)

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

Following code does not work and I do not know why? Both of them are select boxes:

```
$('#sibling_id').change(function(event) {
    var sibling_id_val = this.value;
    $('#child_id').val(sibling_id_val).attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Edit; These are chosen-selectboxes

Here is online: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWRxY/1/

This one does also not work: http://jsfiddle.net/zp2HJ/

Comment: Please define _does not work_. Does replacing `.attr` with `.prop` solve the problem?

Comment: unfortunately neither prop nor attr working..

Comment: It works for me. You have mentioned the chosen plugin but you haven't used it in your fiddle.

Comment: I've ubuntu & firefox and it disables the whole selectbox not that with choosen id. It does also not work without chosen-plugin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the working example, you can see it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wfuBY/

```
see code there --> I dont want to give any licence to stackoverflow
```

greetings e2b

Answer (score 0):

use prop() if you are using jquery  version 1.6+

```
$('#child_id').val(sibling_id_val).prop('disabled', true);
```